# Sorting pixels of a gray-scale image in EmguCV by intensity

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to sort all pixels in a gray-scale image. Its type is:

```
Image<Gray, Byte>
```

I'm also new to EmguCV, have never used it before, but from what I understand about, it is better to use built-in EmguCV tools and functions to perform operations on an image. Instead of working with `Data` propery of my image directly, I would love to sort it with built-in EmguCV tools.

So my question is: Is there a way to sort all pixels in my image by their intensity using built-in EmguCV tools? If there aren't any, how would I go about sorting the pixels then?

The output result should contain the highest values in the top left and the lowest in the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

EmguCV doesn't have any function for what you want. You can use `Array.sort()` func from `Array` class to sort all pixels.

```
Image<Gray, byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>("1.jpg");

byte[] b = img.Bytes;
Array.Sort(b);

byte[, ,] b_img = new byte[img.Width, img.Height, 1];

for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
     {
          b_img[j, i, 0] = b[j + i * img.Width];
     }
}

Image<Gray, byte> img2 = new Image<Gray, byte>(b_img);

pictureBox1.Image = img.Bitmap;
pictureBox2.Image = img2.Bitmap;
```

[image]